# SQL Server DNS Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created an Alias in `SQL Server 2008` and i was able to connect normally on the server where the instance is installed.

But I could not connect to the Alias on another server.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You could try opening the command prompt and use `tracert {alias}` and check the route where does it stops/gets blocked... maybe you have a firewall issue

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

I created a DNS XXX.XXX.0.51

I executed the tracert

tracert SQL1-ST01.DOMAIN.COM [XXX.XXX.0.51]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

Retrieved the server active directory:
AD.DOMAIN.com [XXX.XXX.0.100] reports: Destination host unreachable.

Comment: Looks like a firewall is blocking your access... some ISPs blocks access from external IPs and the only way around is to allow it inside the cPanel...

Comment: I guess this might be the answer you're looking for:
[SQL Server Remote Access](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)

Comment: The firewall is completely disabled.

Maybe I have to create a DNS and use the SETSPN command, do not you think?

Comment: to clear doubts on DNS issues, you could use the IP:port directly and it should work... but i think it's the rules about remote access... most databases deny it for default, you have to enabled and grant your IP access to it...

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a CNAME which is a DNS entry that allows other servers to connect to a server under an aliased name. This comes in handy when migrating a SQL Server that has old application code and no one knows all the connections that are involved. I have always reached out to the sys admin to create this DNS entry but here is an article if you have the permissions to create DNS entries.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/create-an-alias-cname-record-in-dns-for-web1

Comment: Your tip worked.
But I have 2 Stand Alone instances on my server, I was able to create a ALIAS only for 1 instance.

How do I create an alias for the second instance.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for the default instance. Unfortunately, I'm not a DNS administrator so I do not know but I believe it has something to do with setting port numbers and assigning them to an alias. I found this link about it https://mariusschulz.com/blog/how-to-configure-a-sql-server-alias-for-a-named-instance-on-a-development-machine
Please up vote my answer if it helped.

Comment: @FernandoSatonni I just got this working on a new 2019 server I built.  I would be glad to give you the steps I used if it is still useful to you.